How to access my remote-hosted site in a web browser
Warning: I have no idea what I'm doing and I'm learning all this as I go along.
I'm trying to install Mediawiki on a remote server provided by a hosting company. The hosting company installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 on it, then I installed the rest of the LAMP stack via SSH using: sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php php-mysql libapache2-mod-php php-xml php-mbstring
I am now trying to access the site in a browser using the server's IP address like this: http://1.2.3.4. But I only get a connection timeout error. Am I doing it wrong? Even if there's nothing setup right now, I should be able to reach like a blank white screen or a 404 error, right?

You also have to go into the Apache configuration file and tell it to listen to IP addresses other than the loopback port. This is the time you're meant to go through the config file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and confirm that it's set up correctly; and one of the things you will be doing is changing the port definition for the default web site from 127.0.0.1:80 to *:80. Once you've done that, browsing to the IP address should give you an Apache "It Works!" page.

I used grep  "127.0.0.1" * and grep ":80" * and didn't get any hits. Skimming through the files with nano, I saw that /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf start with <VirtualHost *:80>.

Should also check that the Apache service is enabled and started - sudo service apache2 enable, sudo service apache2 start. Some distributions use httpd instead of apache2. The only other thing I'd look at would be your firewall. But there are several and I don't know which one you have installed, so I can't give you exact instructions on opening port 80 to the world.

I fixed it by doing sudo ufw allow 'Apache'. I appreciate your time and advice!
